# Problem Installing Solarized Theme For Emacs Via Melpa

Tags: themes, package-repositories

So currently I have

```
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
```

in my .emacs file. Mind you I am using emacs 24.5. Every single time I run

```
M-x package-install solarized-theme
```

I get no match found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You have to run first `M-x package-list-packages` for Emacs to refresh its package database.

Comment: Had to restart emacs, found package and installed it. Just not through direct command.

Comment: You can also just run `package-refresh-contents` which won't open up the package list but still update the package list.